# Want to call a javascript function with 2 parameters in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP containing JavaScript function.Within that I created an inner html code.That contain a button with onClick function.When clicking the button I want to pass 2 parameters to the the function of JavaScript. But I can't get the 2 values properly.Please help me

Thank you

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function find(){
     var i=0;
     var servicetypevalue="SERVICE";
     var td7= document.createElement("td");     
     td7.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="View Status" class=button name="ptBtn" id="ptBtn" onClick="getStatus('i,servicetypevalue');">';
 }

 function getStatus(i,servicetypevalue){
     alert("enter");
 }
</script>
```

I want to show the enter alert.But the parameter values are not properly passed.

Comment: Try `'<input type="button" value="View Status" class=button name="ptBtn" id="ptBtn" onClick="getStatus('+i+','+servicetypevalue+');">` instead. You need to concatonate the variables to your string. '

Comment: @AdamJeffers is right, moreover you probably need to add quotes around string parameter `onClick="getStatus('+i+', \''+servicetypevalue+'\');"`

Comment: @ VincenzoC Thank you.It works

Answer (score 0):

```
td7.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="View Status" class=button name="ptBtn" id="ptBtn" onClick="getStatus(' + i + ',' + servicetypevalue + ');">';
```

use string concatenation as given above.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e going to generate your own elements in JS, it's different than jQuery.  While in jQuery you can make strings into valid markup reliably, but JS is not as sophisticated. Yes you can make an element by `innerHTML`, but it's error prone. The procedure to accomplish what you want in plain JS is as follows:

#1. Create an element.

#2. Append element to a parent.

#3. Add attributes to element.

The way your code is, it wouldn't work because your'e skipping #2. `.td7` is never appended on the DOM and if the innerHTML of `.td7` was rendered, it might succeed that'd be wierd. Instead of using an inline event which limits you, `addEventListener` gives you much better control and is more manageable. Also your getStatus just alerts *"enter"* which doesn't prove that your 2 parameters actually were passed. I added another alert as proof that the parameters were passed.

```js
var i = 0;
var servicetypevalue = "SERVICE";
var host = document.querySelector('body');
var td7 = document.createElement('td'); //#1
var ptBtn = document.createElement("button"); //#1
host.appendChild(td7); //#2
td7.appendChild(ptBtn); //#2
ptBtn.className = "button"; //#3
ptBtn.name = "ptBtn"; //#3
ptBtn.id = "ptBtn"; //#3
ptBtn.innerHTML = "View Status"; //#3

function getStatus(i, servicetypevalue) {
  alert("enter");
  alert("i: " + i + "\nservicetypevalue: " + servicetypevalue)
}

ptBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  getStatus(i, servicetypevalue);
}, false);

window.load = find;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

```
td7.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="View Status" class=button name="ptBtn" id="ptBtn" onClick="getStatus('i,servicetypevalue');">';
```

to

```
td7.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="View Status" class=button name="ptBtn" id="ptBtn" onClick="' + "getStatus('i','servicetypevalue'" + ');">';
```